# C# best way to call MySQL Stored Procedures, Functions

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, stored-procedures

Hello I wrote my DAL calling Stored Procedures, but I still don't know if I should use ExecuteScalar, NonQuery or Reader for some procedures.

For example I wrote this function that I want to call

```
CREATE FUNCTION `retornarIdArea`(cod longtext) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE id int;
    select AreaId into id FROM area where Codigo = cod;
    return id;
END
```

this procedure that should return a dataset

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `consultar_n_asunto`(in asun longtext, in est int)
BEGIN
    select * from notas where Asunto LIKE CONCAT('%',CONCAT(asun,'%')) AND Estado = est;
END$$
```

And last a procedure that inserts some data, and I validate that with a select using output Parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `registrar_dest`(in nomb longtext,
in dir longtext, in inst int, in mail longtext, in tel longtext,
in act int, out res tinyint(1))
BEGIN
    -- verificar que no exista el destinatario
    select count(*) into res from destinatario WHERE Nombre = nomb AND 
    Direccion = dir AND Email = mail AND Telefono = tel AND Activo = act;

    IF res = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO destinatario (Nombre, Direccion, InstitucionId, Email, Telefono, Activo)
        VALUES (nomb, dir, inst, mail, tel, act);
        select count(*) into res from destinatario WHERE Nombre = nomb AND 
        Direccion = dir AND Email = mail AND Telefono = tel AND Activo = act;
    ELSE 
        set res = -1;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Now I wrote in C# this to return values from FUNCTIONS

> ```
>     public object ejecutarFuncion()
>     {
>         using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(stringDeConexion))
>         {
>             using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(procedimiento, conn))
>             {
>                 cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>                 //Se abre la conexión
>                 conn.Open();
>                 //existen parámetros los recorremos y agregamos.
>                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pars in parametros)
>                 {
>                     cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(pars.Key, pars.Value));
>                 }
>                 //Se crea la variable de retorno
>                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(nombreOut, tipoParOut));
>                 cmd.Parameters[nombreOut].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
>                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>                 // Cerramos conexión
>                 conn.Close();
>                 return cmd.Parameters[nombreOut].Value;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> If you see I do a ExecuteNonQuery() here, but should I used Execute Scalar? or just use the return value from parms?

Then I wrote this method to execute Procedures with output values (some of them do update, insert) operations, I use the output value to check if operation was done correctly.

```
public object ejecutarProcedimientoConOutput()
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(stringDeConexion))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(procedimiento, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //Se abre la conexión
            conn.Open();
            //verificamos si se mando la lista de parámetros
            if (parametros.Count > 0)
            {
                //existen parámetros los recorremos y agregamos.
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pars in parametros)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(pars.Key, pars.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters[pars.Key].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                }
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(nombreOut, tipoParOut));
            cmd.Parameters[nombreOut].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return cmd.Parameters[nombreOut].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Again if I'm doing an update or insert operation, but I use output parameter to check if it was done, you can check the insert stored procedure should I use ExecuteNonQuery or ExecuteScalar?

And for procedures that returns datasets is the same as the method I wrote above, but without the output parameter, I'm using executeReader since I only do a select and not using output parameter.

I just want to know if I'm using the correct execute commands for those procedures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- If you want the number of rows affected by your query to be returned
  then use `ExecuteNonReader()`.
- If you want the first column of the first row to be returned then use
  `ExecuteScalar`.
- If you require a `SqlDataReader` to be created so you can iterate
  over the result then use `ExecuteReader`.

Therefore you could use `ExecuteScalar` for your function `retornarIdArea` since you are only ever returning one column and one row (the id) so this function fits the context.

For your procedure `consultar_n_asunto` you could use `ExecuteReader` as you are selecting multiple rows and expect the result set to be returned.